# How can i perform action to other view from one view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop, class, object

In my objective-c program, i used the tab bar to separate different function for this apps. the first view in the tab bar shows same table view contents between second view, i would like when the user click the first view's cell, it will turn to second view and perform :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and the parameter "indexPath is the first view indexPath which the user selected.

Pls help~~

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

yourself. You should set a delegate to the tableView and this method will be called automatically on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
    //from firstviewcontroller;
    (SecondViewController *)secondvc;
    [secondvc [tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath]];
```

But then again you will have to provide the data necessary for the function. If you're just pulling the indexPath, make sure it's the same indexPath from the other table.
I mean, it seems you have two different tables and you're trying to execute a function from table A into table B and that could be quite confusing

Comment: and don't forget to add @property in the H file.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController (SecondViewController *)secondvc